# How to extract path names without including file names

Tags: python, parsing, url, path

There is url like the following.

```
original = 'https://dev.s3.amazonaws.com/production/uploads/2017/11/filename.jpg'
```

I want to extract `/production/uploads/2017/11` only from this.
It is possible to extract just the file name and extract the path including the file name, but please tell me if there is a good way to extract the path excluding the file name.

```
original_image_name = original.split('/')[-1] # 'filename.jpg'

from urllib.parse import urlparse
original_image_url = urlparse(original)
original_image_path = original_image_url.path # '/production/uploads/2017/11/filename.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(original_image_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html), like this one:

```
(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+)(.*)
```

See this for a live demo: https://regex101.com/r/2jsyiI/2

Answer (score 0):

urllib has the adequate tools for this:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse

Answer (score 0):

You will get expected output

```
original = "https://dev.s3.amazonaws.com/production/uploads/2017/11/filename.jpg"

test = original.split("/")
test = test[3:]
test = test[:-1]
sd = '/'.join(test)
print sd
```

> OUTPUT

```
production/uploads/2017/11
```